# CakePHP How can I save many records in a link table at once for user - map - attributes?

Tags: cakephp, save, has-many-through, has-many

I have three tables/models:

```
User(id)
Map(id, user_id, attribute_id)
Attribute (id, name)
```

Map belongsTo the others, the others hasMany Map.

I'd like the user (via user controller and user view) to create many links to associations at once. How can I do this, assuming that the user forms (add/edit) have 10 attribute fields, all linking to the same table?

I'd need to save up to 10 records in Map in one go. To start with, I'm unsure what the field should be - create('Attribute.name')? Also, cake outputs the same input name to each input as they point to the same field - what's the best way to fix this?

I have already read the relevant documentation, but didn't get much from it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [saveAssociated() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array). Prepare an input array according to the instructions given in the link and directly use `$this->User->saveAssociated($your_array, array('deep' => true));`

Comment: That link doesn't help. Find if I want to save a user or attribute, but I don't, I need so save a link between them. I can see how I might do that manually, passing an id for each, but I think cake is supposed to be able to do this automatically? It's a hasManyThrough